# RecyclerView as item of RecyclerView - performance wise

Tags: android, performance, listview, android-recyclerview

I have a `RecyclerView` in my application and one of the row has to contain contact information like website addresses, phone numbers, etc.

It is possible that user has many phone numbers or even none. The layout for presenting phone number would be the same as for presenting website addresses.

I am not sure what would be a good practice for doing such things. Should I make a `RecyclerView` as item for the main `RecyclerView` and then populate Adapter with some `ViewDescriptors`? Or should I just put them inside `LinearLayout` and populate it from code?

I am afraid that using `RecyclerView` as item for `RecyclerView` would make this item layout very heavy and scrolling would not be smooth.

Comment: It is ok to use both `ListView` and `RecyclerView`